# Show that $(H, \circ)$ is a subgroup of the group $G$

Tags: group-theory, equivalence-relations

**Question:** Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a nonempty subset of $G$. A relation $\rho$ defined on $G$ by ``$a\rho b$ if and only if $a\circ b^{-1}\in H$" for $a,b\in G$, is an equivalence relation on $G$. Prove that $(H,\circ)$ is a subgroup of $(G, \circ)$.

**Answer:** Let $a\in G$, then  $a\rho a $ holds and so $a\circ a^{-1}=e\in H$
So $H$ contains identity element.
I don't know whether my approach is right or not. How can I show that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.
Thaks

Comment: Welcome to our site!

Comment: Use symmetry of $\rho$ on $a\rho e$ and $e\rho a$ for inverses.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right way.

You already proved that reflexivity of the equivalence relation implies that $e\in H$. Similarly other properties of equivalence relations imply that $H$ is a subgroup:

Since $a\rho b\Leftrightarrow b\rho a$, we have $a\circ b^{-1} \in H \Leftrightarrow b \circ a^{-1} = (a \circ b^{-1})^{-1} \in H$, so $H$ is closed under taking inverses (note that any element $h\in H$ can be represented as a product $a\circ b^{-1}$, just let $a=h$ and $b=e$).

Now, let $x,y \in H$. Let $a=x$, $b=e$, $c=y^{-1}$. Transitivity $a\rho b \land b\rho c \Rightarrow a\rho c$ implies $a\circ b^{-1} = 
x \in H \land b\circ c^{-1} = y \in H \Rightarrow a\circ c^{-1} = x\circ y \in H$, so $H$ is closed under group operation.

Answer (score 1):

You are starting out good.  Now, suppose that $a\in H$.  Then you get $a\circ e^{-1}=a \in H$.  By symmetry, $e\circ a^{-1}=a^{-1}\in H.$

Then all you have to do is closure under multiplication, which is transitivity.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good first step, the next step is to check if $ab\in H$ and that inverses exist. These can be done at once by checking if $ab^{-1}\in H$ which we can easily do because if $a,b\in H$ then $a\rho b$ which means that  $ab^{-1}\in H$ by definition of the relation, you're done.